# Left join with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

**My tables**

```
functions_groups
+---------------+----------+
| function_name | group_id |
+---------------+----------+
| function1     | 46       |
| function1     | 47       |
| function2     | 46       |
+---------------+----------+

groups
+----------+------------+
| group_id | group_name |
+----------+------------+
| 46       | Group46    |
| 47       | Group47    |
+----------+------------+
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| Function  | Groups               |
+-----------+----------------------+
| function1 | Group46, Group47     |
| function2 | Group46              |
+-----------+----------------------+
```

**My query until yet (which gives me empty rows/cells)**

```
SELECT
    fg.function_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS group_names
FROM functions_groups fg
LEFT JOIN groups g
    ON g.group_id = fg.group_id
```

How can I fix this, so that I grab the multiple values (seperated with commas) from the left join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a DB query for you. I hope it will resolve your problem :

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    f.function_name 'Function', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_name) 'Groups'
FROM
    functions_groups f
        LEFT JOIN
    groups g ON g.group_id = f.group_id
GROUP BY function_name;
```